# using samsung galaxy 5 as device in eclipse

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile

I can't manage to use my Samsung Galaxy 5 from my eclipse. For example I can't debug  my app when connecting the s5 to my computer. I see the device in 'devices' but its unknown or offline. I have activated debugmode in the developer options.

Its working for other devices like samsung galaxy tab 10.

Any hints ?

[image]

Comment: I just restarted eclipse and my samsung galaxy s5. Then a popup appeared on the device, which i see the first time to allow connectivity in Debugmode with the pc. I accepted and it works !! What shall I do with this question ? delete ?

Comment: I had the exact same problem, so your question (and solution) actually helped me, as once I restarted my phone I got the RSA key popup and now it works, so thanks, it was getting really frustrating :)

Comment: I have the same issue but restarting my phone hasn't solved the problem! :( what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

There is a small "secret" to get this to work for Samsung Galaxy S5. The Development options menu in Settings is hidden by default. You can make it visible by going to "About device" and then tapping on "Build number" seven times. Yes, seven times. It's like Dorothy in Wizard of Oz, only the magic number is 7 not 3.

After that, "Developer options" will be visible, and there you an put the phone into USB debugging mode.

Answer (score 0):

may be this is your data cable fault..

previously it's happens to me also
after changing my data cable

problem is solved

sometimes, some data cable is not supported for adb interface
like..
same cable is working fine with galaxy tab 10 but not supported with s5.

Answer (score 0):

restart your device and then enable USB debugging mode, 
you should get a RSA key popup, just click OK and it should work :)