# Can not Run my Application on Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, samsung-mobile

First of all I must say that I have been working around this issue for two whole days and I can not solve it. I googled it, I read [this](http://donandroid.com/how-to-install-adb-interface-drivers-windows-7-xp-vista-623) article from Donandroid, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534025/using-samsung-galaxy-5-as-device-in-eclipse) from SO and many other reviews.

I have installed `Samsung Kies3`, `Android sdk for windows`, `google_usb_driver` on my windows 7 64-bit system. I also check the `USB Debugging` option in my Galaxy S5 and restart my phone. I also have restarted the `ADT`

Now when I check the attached devices in `adb`, I get:

```
$adb devices
$List of devices attached
4d0005444cc34139    unauthorized
```

I have tried to run my application on this device, but I have got this in `ADT`:
[image]

I have no idea what to do now. I am totally frustrated. Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

Comment: have u installed samsung kite?

Comment: @Dipu yes I have installed Samsung Kies

Comment: usb debugging enabled?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes but I have not seen any popup authorization message on my phone yet

Comment: if You connect the phone, it should be possible to select between camera option and device option by pulling down the notification bar. Do you have this option and if yes, just try to switch two times. Sometimes my GS3 has the same problems and after switching it will be noticed...maybe this helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, solve the problem. I have unplugged/plunged the usb cable for 3 times and suddenly the popup authorization message showed up on my phone. I allowed that and now everything is fine. I can not believe I spent two days in this issue. Hope this thread will help someone.

Comment: very thanks, I have unplugged/plunged the usb cable for 3 times and suddenly the popup authorization message showed up on my phone, too.

Comment: +1 for unplugging and replugging, but it seemed to only work when you are past the phone's lock screen. In other words, it would not show a dialog on a lock screen and when you open the phone, the dialog was not there.

Comment: Same here -  nothing I tried would allow Eclipse to see my Galaxy S5 even though I had enabled all the developer options and even though this same cable and development environment worked fine with my S3, and my Galaxy Tab 4 and a stack of cheaper older Samsungs.   So I did the plugging-and-unplugging-3-times and it worked!!    **Very weird**.